# How can I see the order of accuracy of an ODE method?

Tags: numerical-methods

Let's say I have solved an ODE with Euler's forward method, and also solved it using RK4, in both cases for varying decreasing step sizes $h$. Is there any way to look at the graphs and "see" the order of accuracy of the methods?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, graph the differences of the results for stepsizes $h$ and $2h$ as double-logarithmic plot. The graph should be of lines, and the slopes correspond to the order of the method.

---

More precisely, the numerical result for step size $h$ is in first order of approximation 
$$
y_h=y_*+C·h^p+D/h
$$
where $C$ accumulates the derivative factors for the method error and $D$ accounts for the floating point errors in the evaluation of every single step.

Thus the mentioned difference gives
$$
y_{2h}-y_h=(2^p-1)·C·h^p-D/(2h)
$$
so that for moderately small $h\gg \sqrt[p+1]{D/C}$ one gets
$$
\log(y_{2h}-y_h)\approx\log((2^p-1)·C)+p·\log(h)
$$